# Laravel phpunit HTTP testing - как тестируют авторизованные страницы?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Пытаюсь изучить phpunit testing, но споткнулся на авторизированных страницах.  Не совсем понятно «как же собственно тестировать авторизованные страницы», если Laravel после авторизации создает специальные куки и уже на основании их решает — разрешать/запрещать . *Более полный пример* того, что пытаюсь сделать — а) проверяю возможность залогинится, б) «проверяю роут(admin) и вьюшку:

```
class AuthUsersTest extends TestCase
{

    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test_user_can_login_with_correct_credentials()
    {
        $user = factory('App\User')->create([
            'password' => bcrypt($password = 'SuperPassword'),
        ]);

        $response = $this->post('/login', [
            'name' => $user->name,
            'password' => $password,
        ]);

        $response->assertRedirect('/admin');
        $this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user);
// trying to understand what i can do with cookies
        $cookieName = $response->headers->getCookies()[0]->getName();
        $response->assertCookieNotExpired($cookieName);
    }

    public function test_auth_user_can_see_dashboard()
    {
        $this->withExceptionHandling();
        $response = $this->actingAs(factory('App\User')->make())
            ->get('/admin');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

но response->assertStatus — неожиданно возвращает 500 . 
[image: Результат вызова теста]

Проблема, мне так кажется, в отсутствующей куке с данными об авторизации (id, token etc). Теоретически эти куки можно попробовать изъять и подставить(они создаются при логине ) , но уж больно велосипедно выглядеть начинает и не факт, что сработает.

Собственно вопросы:

1. Возможно я забыл что то подключить из трейтов? Помимо RefreshDatabase есть ли какой то дополнительный трейт "отвечающий за эмуляцию авторизации"?
2. Может вместе с actingAs нужно передавать куки о авторизации пользователя?
3. Может это вообще как то по другому тестируется?

Comment: Смотрите логи сервера, у вас сделано по [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/master/http-tests#session-and-authentication), так что код правильный - вероятно что-то еще не так.

Comment: возможно по пути '/admin' для пользователя вылезает ошибка. Попробуйте `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` первой строкой теста, чтобы видеть ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проковырявшись кучу времени - проблему таки решил, сменив рабочее окружение - Open Server на хост, развернутый на Vagrant-e. Собственно подсказка была в 500 ошибке сервера.